# How to append text to array value JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two javascript array like this.

```
var category = ['Jacket'];
var subcategory = ['Woman', 'Men', 'Kids'];
```

and i want combining array value like this

```
var finalCategory = ['Jacket Woman', 'Jacket Men', 'Jacket Kids'];
```

if category more than one, final result

```
var category = ['Jacket', 'Bags'];
var subcategory = ['Woman', 'Men', 'Kids'];
var finalCategory = ['Jacket Woman', 'Jacket Men', 'Jacket Kids', 'Bags Woman', 'Bags Men', 'Bags Kids'];
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: So if `category` array contains >1 item, what then?

Comment: try to read docs

Comment: What you are looking for is `Array.map`

Comment: @Jamiec , thank you, i miss about it., question update

Comment: @Rajesh , can you tell me some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var category = ['Jacket', 'Bags'];
var subcategory = ['Woman', 'Men', 'Kids'];
var combos = [];
category.forEach(function(a){
    subcategory.forEach(function(b){
        combos.push(a + ' ' + b);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You could create the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) with nested loops as result.

```js
var category = ['Jacket', 'Bags'],
    subcategory = ['Woman', 'Men', 'Kids'],
    result = category.reduce(function (r, a) {         // use an accumulator and item
        return r.concat(subcategory.map(function (b) { // concat result of mapped subs
            return [a, b].join(' ');                   // build string with given items
        }));
    }, []);                                            // take array as accumulator

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var category = ['Jacket', 'Bags'],
    subcategory = ['Woman', 'Men', 'Kids'],
    result = category.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(subcategory.map(b => [a, b].join(' '))), []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you add a brief explanation on each line. you really are fond of array i always see your answer with arrays :)

Comment: @guradio, i like arrays :-)

Comment: explanation will really help future readers as well as users like me. great answer as always happy coding

Answer (score 3):

```
var category = ['Jacket', 'Bags'];
var subcategory = ['Woman', 'Men', 'Kids'];
var finalCategory = []

for(var i = 0; i < category.length; i++){
    for(var ii = 0; ii < subcategory.length; ii++){
        finalCategory.push(category[i] + ' ' + subcategory[ii])    
    }
}
console.log(finalCategory)
```

Nested loop. One covering all main categorys, then covering sub categories within it.

Comment: Thank you for helped me and other people, i select best anwer with small and clean code.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested for loops to create a new array:

```js
function concatArr(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArr = [];
  for (var a = 0; a < arr1.length; a++) {
    var arr1Value = arr1[a];
    for (var b = 0; b < arr2.length; b++) {
      var arr2Value = arr2[b];
      newArr.push(arr1Value + " " + arr2Value);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
//TEST
var category = ['Jacket', 'Pants'];
var subcategory = ['Woman', 'Men', 'Kids'];
console.log(concatArr(category, subcategory));
```